# Check Boxes - images instead of True False values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have created a dependent drop-down list for my data but I would like to know if there is when filtering my original data to get the values in col F, G, and H as a check box instead of True and false values. I would appreciate any help to solve this issue.
Best,
here is the link to the spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCG3eVUCxSPNIXQJExX0CAT6cGEnMq0qOQfOjogw8RY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean with "get the values in col F, G, and H as a check box instead of True and false values"?

Comment: See sheet4. I have a filter than can change True, and False values to a check box shape

Comment: I posted an answer base on the information in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select *one* of the cells you expect to display those `true` and `false` values and choose **Insert > Checkbox** to format the cell as a checkbox. Then set the value in that checkbox cell `null` by removing the `false` value in the formula bar. Finally, copy the checkbox across the row and down as far as necessary.

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCG3eVUCxSPNIXQJExX0CAT6cGEnMq0qOQfOjogw8RY/edit#gid=1586308727) for an illustration.

To hide "unneeded" checkboxes in rows where there is no data yet, use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule to set the text color of the cell to match cell's fill color when the row is blank. That will make a checkbox invisible.

Comment: If you insert a checkbox the formula will stop working when there are so many rows to filter because it will overwrite the checkbox you inserted manually. So this is not a solution

Comment: The formula will continue to work fine provided that the checkboxes you insert have a value of `null`. You can insert such checkboxes all the way down. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCG3eVUCxSPNIXQJExX0CAT6cGEnMq0qOQfOjogw8RY/edit#gid=1586308727) for an illustration. See [threeStateCheckboxes_](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/162507/269219) to better understand what is going on.

Comment: I did as you said the formula stopped working. See your solution tab as well. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCG3eVUCxSPNIXQJExX0CAT6cGEnMq0qOQfOjogw8RY/edit#gid=1586308727) sheet seems to be working fine. Ditto for the 'Filter View' sheet. There are invisible checkboxes in columns `E:G` all the way down, each with a `null` value. It is unclear what you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of Google [here](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308622).

> In formulas, unselected checkboxes have a value of FALSE (exclude) and selected checkboxes have a value of TRUE (include).

So essentially, using TRUE or FALSE in a formula is already using checkboxes. The checkboxes that you see are a graphic representation of TRUE or FALSE when used in a formula you cannot use a graphic representation, and that is why you need to use TRUE or FALSE.